# pymongo single insert is too slow, despite WriteConcern(w=0)

Tags: python, mongodb, performance, time, pymongo

I am using pymongo to write to my mongodb.
I want as fast as possible performance, so I set the write concern to w=0. I tried three ways:

1.

```
client = MongoClient(host=HOST, port=PORT, w=0)
collection = client[DB][COLLECTION]
collection.insert_one(data)
```

2.

```
client = MongoClient(host=HOST, port=PORT)
collection = collection.with_options(write_concern=WriteConcern(w=0))
collection = client[DB][COLLECTION]
collection.insert_one(data)
```

3.

```
client = MongoClient(host=HOST, port=PORT)
collection = client[DB][COLLECTION]
collection.insert_one(data, bypass_document_validation=True)
```

In all above attempts, the time it took for collection.insert_one() was ~0.5 seconds (!)

Why is insertion still taking so long?

I understand that it should be about a fifth of that time at least. More so, 'data' is not a lot of data, only a few items. I am using mongodb 3.4 and pymongo 3.0

Answer (score 1):

First, you would need to answer "how fast is fast enough".

"Slow" and "fast" are very subjective terms. It depends on so many factors, including the provisioned server, the language you're using, the document you're inserting, how many indexes you defined in the collection, all the way to your expectations.

For some people, "slow" is >100ms. For others, "slow" is >10ms. Of course, the "faster" you want to get results, the more expensive it will cost you in terms of server provisioning.

On another note, Python is not the fastest language. It is well known to have limitations in terms of its use of the [Global Interpreter Lock](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock). It's also an interpreted language, and designed primarily for readability and not for sheer speed. You can usually get an immediate speed boost using a compiled language (C, C++, etc.)

Another thing you can try is to use bulk insert, and not trying to insert many documents using `insert_one()`. Please see http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/examples/bulk.html#bulk-insert for examples using bulk insert.

Comment: Thank you. What concerned me most is that the time it took for insert_one() was very much similar before and after I added the write concern. Could it be it did not have the right affect? Regarding bulk insert, it is problematic for me because I want to write to the db a small amount on each application run.

Comment: @KerenMeron in that case, the roundtrip time to access the database from your application is much greater than the delay between the replica set nodes or the amount of time it took to write to the journal. Remember that MongoDB is a distributed database, which means that the network situation must be taken into account for time-sensitive application. WriteConcern could make things faster, but it can't be faster than your network.

Answer (score 0):

`w=0` won't help unless you're running a cluster. [1]

`co = co.with_options(write_concern=WriteConcern(w=0, j=False, fsync=False))` sped things up significantly for me, but make sure you understand the consequences. Probably better to use `insert_many` to speed things up (especially if your mongodb server is on the network).

EDIT: might've been a fluke actually - slowed down after a while.

[1] https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/write_concern.html#pymongo.write_concern.WriteConcern